# jquery selecting the next div when that div has children

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to be able to select the div next in line (its not a child div, or a parent div) more like a sibling.  Then I want to get the node_id from that div and parse it.  For example, below I know the "NODE_ID" of the first one, so I can use a jquery selector to get that node_ID, then I want to move directly beneath that DIV and retrieve the NODE_ID of that one, but I won't know the ID, or Node_id, so I have to be able to get to the next DIV without an id for a selector...in this case I want to retrieve the node_id value "74_3" and parse it.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div style="display: block;" id="71_2_sub_p_div" node_id="72_2">
    <span class="a_hand">
        <img src="../images/maximize.png"> &nbsp;Commercial
    </span>
</div>

<div style="display: block;" id="71_3_sub_p_div" node_id="74_3">
    <span onclick="toggle_display('75_4_sub_p_div');" class="a_hand">
           <img src="../images/maximize.png"> &nbsp;Apartments
    </span>
</div>
```

Here is the selector I'm using to get the Known NODE_ID's:

```
$("div[node_id='72_2']")
```

How can I do this in jquery?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the div is the next sibling, you can use [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
$('div[node_id=72_2]').next(); // should be div#71_3_sub_p_div
$('div[node_id=72_2]').next().attr('node_id'); // should be '74_3'
```

If there are other siblings, and you only want to find `<div node_id='...'>`'s you can get a little more complicated:

```
$('div[node_id=72_2]').nextAll('div[node_id]').eq(0).attr('node_id') 
// also '74_3'
```

Looks through all the next siblings looking for divs with the node_id attribute, reduces the match to a single item using [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq) and then returns it's node_id attribute.

Comment: Instead of using `.slice(0,1)` you should better use `.first()`: http://api.jquery.com/first/

Comment: `.first()` just calls `this.eq(0)` so, I just used `eq(0)`, which interestingly just calls `this.slice(0,1)` so, its all the same, and `.slice()` requires 2 less function calls than `.first()`

Comment: `first` returns a jQuery object of the first element; `get(0)` returns the DOM element itself.

Comment: @matt - Yes, I know this. `.eq(0)` and `.slice(0,1)` return a jQuery objects as well.

Comment: Sorry... I'm just an idiot who can't differentiate between `eq` and `get` :P